# How can I make Sublime Text reload the file being edited?

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

How can I make Sublime Text (3) re-load the file currently being edited, to take into account changes having been made externally?

Comment: It does automatically already. I am looking a solution to prevent it.

Comment: @atilkan `always_prompt_for_file_reload` has to be set to  `true` in settings.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To re-load the current file, you can revert the file, either through the menu entry `File | Revert File` or through the command `File: Revert` (open the command palette by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `revert`).

To make it easier in the future, you can bind a shortcut to the revert command, for example <kbd>F5</kbd>, simply by adding an entry to your key bindings (`Preferences | Key Bindings - User`):

```
{
    "keys": ["f5"],
    "command": "revert"
}
```

Comment: "revert"?! Uggh. I thought that did something else. Thanks!

Comment: Reverting causes the file to go blank :(
  Sublime build 3114.

Comment: Right answer, but this keybind is unwise a bit

Comment: @Apeiron why do you say the keybind is unwise?

Comment: this does not reload files loaded via FTPS

Answer (score 9):

Although there is an accepted answer, it requires that we have to refresh manually everytime by pressing F5. Try this package `Auto Refresh` [here](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Auto%20Refresh). This automatically refreshes the file in x seconds which is configurable.

Comment: I'm guessing "automatic" was the original intention of the question though not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

Though asked more than a year ago: you can also use "File->Reopen with encoding..." command. Note, all your changes made so far will be discarded while performing reload/revert

Comment: how can we do this to all files, not just individually, manually? and how can we make it do this right away, rather than having to trigger it manually after a merge or checkout?

Comment: What's the point of making such a note. How do I open a door? Well, you open a door, but note the door will be open. Wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I just realized that when switching from the search bar to the main editor panel, it refresh the view.

So ctrl+F then escape.

Not the best, but no configuration or clicking required. Also, I would expect it not to work if you have unsaved edition.