# Sublime text duplicate open of the same file

Tags: sublime-text-3

I work on HPC (cluster running on Slurm system) and I use a GUI similar to WinSCP.

When running a simulation, the output files are constantly updated. I usually open the output files during the simulation to check the status of the simulation. So, in Notepad++ when I open the output file that I already opened before and didn't close, it will just be updated and not open another tab of the same file.

However, Sublime text will open the same file (but updated) in a new tab and will display long names of both files which can be confusing.

Is there a way to make sublime text behave like notepad++ in this matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Sublime Text reload the file being edited?](https://superuser.com/questions/815045/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-reload-the-file-being-edited)